# Why was bounty not awarded?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I'd like to understand better the bounty system. Apparently the bounty on question [Gateway / Switch hybrid](https://superuser.com/questions/307638/gateway-switch-hybrid/309858#309858) wasn't awarded by the questioner. But also not by the system itself when the period expired.

I've read the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#bounty) concerning bounties and cannot match this behavior with what is written there. Could someone please help me understand what were the conditions that invalidated the bounty award?

Comment: Ok folks. Thanks for your answers. It's clarified :)

Comment: FYI, I've put in a [request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98987/147926) on MSO to have the FAQ updated.

Comment: Thank you. I was planning to do it too. Glad it's covered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bounties now get a 24hours grace period after they expire in which the person posting the bounty can award it before it is dealt with automatically. After this timer expires, and assuming the person posting the bounty doesn't manually award it, the bounty will follow the automatic award pattern as detailed in the FAQ.

This is quite a new change:

> **[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037)**
>   due to a lot of <strike>whining</strike> valued community feedback on this issue, I decided it can't hurt to extend the auto-award period 24 hours past the true end of the bounty. So, the question will stop being a bounty question at the original scheduled time but the auto-accept calculations will always occur 24 hours after that.

You are correct that this doesn't seem to be reflected in the FAQ correctly.

---

Also missing from the FAQ seems to be note that the full bounty will be auto-awarded to the accepted answer (if there is one and the question owner posted the bounty) in preference to the highest scoring answer, also a fairly recent change:

> **[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55199/why-didnt-i-get-the-bounty/91442#91442)**
>   If ...
>
> - the bounty was started by the question owner
> - the question owner accepts an answer *during the bounty period*
> - the bounty award period expires without an explicit award
>
> ... then we assume the question owner liked your answer when they
>   accepted it, and it gets the full amount of the bounty **at time of
>   bounty expiration**.

Answer (score 3):

Bounty rules have changed a bit. The time for auto-awarding of bounties has been [extended by 24 hours:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68050/133693)

> I decided it can't hurt to extend the auto-award period 24 hours past the true end of the bounty. **So, the question will stop being a bounty question at the original scheduled time but the auto-accept calculations will always occur 24 hours after that.**

Since the OP has not awarded the bounty, your answer will be awarded the bounty 20 hours from the time this answer was written.